# Jooq command fails after upgrading to Spring Boot 3.0.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, jooq

since the upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.1 the Jooq commands (Select Statements) are failing when using the external db.
For local db everything is still working.
The external db is still reachable and I can use it as before with an sql-editor.

My Jooq-Config:

```
@Configuration
public class JooqConfig {
    @Bean
    Settings jooqSettings() {
        return new Settings()
                .withRenderSchema(false);
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.jooq.sql-dialect=mysql

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db // or external db
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "${springBootVersion}"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    id("nu.studer.jooq") version "8.0"
}

java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

dependencies {
    ...

    // Jooq
    implementation("org.jooq:jooq:3.17.6")
    implementation("org.jooq:jooq-meta:3.17.6")
    implementation("org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.17.6")
    jooqGenerator("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.30")
    jooqGenerator('jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0')

    ...
}


jooq {
    version = '3.17.6'  // default (can be omitted)
    edition = nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqEdition.OSS  // default (can be omitted)

    configurations {
        main {  // name of the jOOQ configuration
            generateSchemaSourceOnCompilation = true  // default (can be omitted)

            generationTool {

                jdbc {
                    driver = 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'
                    url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db'
                    user = ''
                    password = ''

                }
                generator {
                    name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator'
                    database {
                        name = 'org.jooq.meta.mysql.MySQLDatabase'
                        inputSchema = 'XXX'
                    }
                    generate {
                        deprecated = false
                        records = true
                        immutablePojos = true
                        fluentSetters = true
                    }
                    target {
                        packageName = 'app.jooq'
                        directory = 'src/main/src-gen'
                    }
                    strategy.name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
tasks.named('generateJooq').configure { allInputsDeclared = true }
```

Example Stacktrace when the error occurs:

```
2022-12-30T07:43:24.259+01:00 ERROR 20964 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: jOOQ; bad SQL grammar [select `XXX`.`user`.`id`, `XXX`.`user`.`first_name`, `XXX`.`user`.`last_name`, `XXX`.`user`.`email`, `XXX`.`user`.`isadmin`,  from `XXX`.`user` left outer join `XXX`.`country` on `XXX`.`user`.`country_id` = `XXX`.`country`.`id` where `XXX`.`user`.`id` = ?]] with root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: SELECT command denied to user 'XXX'@'XXX' for table 'user'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.execute(ClientPreparedStatement.java:354) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:219) ~[jooq-3.17.4.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.executeStatementAndGetFirstResultSet(Tools.java:4562) ~[jooq-3.17.4.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:236) ~[jooq-3.17.4.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:341) ~[jooq-3.17.4.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazy(AbstractResultQuery.java:301) ~[jooq-3.17.4.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazyNonAutoClosing(AbstractResultQuery.java:322) ~[jooq-3.17.4.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetchLazyNonAutoClosing(SelectImpl.java:2861) ~[jooq-3.17.4.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.ResultQueryTrait.fetchOne(ResultQueryTrait.java:509) ~[jooq-3.17.4.jar:na]
    at com.XXX.app.Repository.Impl.UserRepositoryImpl.getUserEntry(UserRepositoryImpl.java:124) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.XXX.app.Repository.Impl.UserRepositoryImpl$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getUserEntry(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.XXX.app.Controller.UserDataController.isEmailVerified(UserDataController.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1010) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:902) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$FilterObservation$SimpleFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:399) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:297) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator.lambda$wrapSecured$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:79) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:125) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:145) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:280) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please also include the error details(stacktrace?) about `are failing when using the external db`

Comment: It seems that the *JooqConfig* is no longer working as the Schema is added to the Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've updated Jooq to the latest available version it seems that the Configuration changed and now the following Config is needed to be applied:

```
@Configuration
public class JooqConfig {

    @Bean
    public DefaultConfigurationCustomizer configurationCustomizer() {
        return (DefaultConfiguration c) -> c.settings()
                .withRenderSchema(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).